# Error while starting Docker daemon

Tags: gentoo, docker, daemon, openrc

I am using Gentoo as Host OS for Docker containers. I have compiled kernel using instructions on page https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Docker#Kernel and I have installed Docker from Gentoo repository.

Host system informations:

```
pecan@tux ~ $ uname -a
Linux tux 4.12.12-gentoo #8 SMP Sat Oct 7 13:58:47 CEST 2017 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Docker version:

```
pecan@tux ~ $ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.2-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.9.1
 Git commit:   f5ec1e2
 Built:        Sat Oct  7 14:50:59 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Look at "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?". The same message appears if I try get docker system-wide informations:

```
pecan@tux ~ $ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

The same error appears if I try run the same command as sudo, so this error applies to daemon. I tried to check if there a mistake in Docker daemon privileges.

```
pecan@tux ~ $ sudo docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Based on the message I am able to say that maybe Docker daemon not running. I checked daemon status to make sure:

```
pecan@tux ~ $ sudo service docker status
 * status: crashed
```

Docker daemon is crashed. To see the reason, I looked at the logs:

```
pecan@tux ~ $ cat /var/log/docker.log 
time="2017-10-07T14:52:13.178261811+02:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 32311" 
time="2017-10-07T14:52:14.434232306+02:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds" 
time="2017-10-07T14:52:14.434413425+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight" 
time="2017-10-07T14:52:14.434423960+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device" 
time="2017-10-07T14:52:14.434759986+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start." 
time="2017-10-07T14:52:14.437180876+02:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false" 
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: list bridge addresses failed: no available network
```

Currently, that is a point in that I do not know what should I do to be able run Docker daemon.

Useful informations:

- I am connected to OpenVPN through UDP.
- I have disabled iptables and ip6tables.
- I have set 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 DNS providers.
- I have running privoxy and tor daemons.
- I use OpenRC init system.

Can you help me?

Comment: How did you install docker? You might be missing the `docker0` bridge. `ip li sh`

Answer (score 0):

Your log says that you don't have some necessary configurations in your kernel...

Specifically `cgroup` `blkio` `weight` and `weight_device`

You should take special care to that part

> For the most up-to-date values check the contents of the `CONFIG_CHECK in /usr/portage/app-emulation/docker/docker-9999.ebuild file.